# Acquiring positive integer from user with HasNextInt method

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and am working on a simple program that should acquire a positive integer from a user. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Binary{
  public static void main( String [] args ){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = getInt(console, "Enter a positive integer");
    System.out.println(number);
  }

  public static int getInt(Scanner console, String prompt){
    System.out.println(prompt);
    while(!console.hasNextInt() || console.nextInt() < 0){
      console.next();
      System.out.println("Not an integer; try again");
      System.out.println(prompt);
    }

    return console.nextInt();


  }  

}
```

Presently, when any integer is entered, it's generating two input fields, and I would like to know how the while loop can be restructured so that it only presents one field after the prompt. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!console.hasNextInt() || console.nextInt() < 0){
  console.next();
  System.out.println("Not an integer; try again");
  System.out.println(prompt);
}
```

You will ask for a new variable in the condition already.

Construct it like this:

```
int input = console.nextInt();

while(!console.hasNextInt() || input < 0){
      System.out.println("Not an integer; try again");
      System.out.println(prompt);
      input = console.nextInt();
}
```

Or perhaps more appropriate:

```
do {
      input = console.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Not an integer; try again");
      System.out.println(prompt);
} while (!console.hasNextInt() || input < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, Try,

```
public static int getInt(Scanner console, String prompt){
   System.out.println(prompt);
   int num;

  while(console.hasNextInt()){
    num= console.nextInt();

    if(num >= 0){// If num is positive than break loop and return num
     break;
    }

   System.out.println("Not an integer; try again");
   System.out.println(prompt);
   }
    return num;
  }
```